# What is the sum of the given series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

How do I sum the following series...

$$ \sum_{r = 0}^{40}{r\binom{40}{r}\binom{30}{r}}$$
When I expanded, I noticed, it turns out to be...

$$0\times\binom{40}{0}\binom{30}{0}+1\times\binom{40}{1}\binom{30}{1}+2\times\binom{40}{2}\binom{30}{2}+3\times\binom{40}{3}\binom{30}{3}+....$$and so on.

So I think that the approach can be to differentiate $$(x+1)^n $$ and its expansion so that the powers of the $x,x^2,x^3,...$ terms get multiplied in front as $1,2,3,4....$, but I can't figure out the approach for two different combinations multiplied together.

Also, for $r>30$, the $\binom{30}{r}$ terms become undefined right? So how do I handle those?

Comment: ${30\choose r}=0$ if $r>30$.

Comment: @saulspatz ah ohk, I guessed that would be the only logical way....but could you tell me how to handle the rest of the terms?

Comment: Have you look at lab's answer?

Comment: @saulspatz just saw now...it hadn't loaded for me then yet!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $r>0,$ $$r\binom{40}r=40\binom{39}{r-1}$$

Now consider $$(1+x)^{39}\left(1+\dfrac1x\right)^{30}=\dfrac{(1+x)^{69}}{x^{30}}$$

Compare the coefficients of $x^{39-(r-1)-(30-r)}$

Comment: Could you explain the second step? Why should I take $(1+\frac{1}{x})^{30}$? Why should I replace $x$ with $\frac{1}{x}$?

Comment: @Techie5879, To get constant exponent of $x$ which can be reached by using $$(1+x)^{39}(x+1)^{50}$$ as well

Comment: Could you please elaborate on why I need to and how I can compare the required coeffs? This is the first problem of this kind and its really confusing for me

Answer (score 2):

$$
\eqalign{
  & \sum\limits_{r = 0}^{40} {r\left( \matrix{
  40 \cr 
  r \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{
  30 \cr 
  r \cr}  \right)}  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{r = 1}^{\left( {30} \right)} {r\left( \matrix{
  40 \cr 
  r \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{
  30 \cr 
  r \cr}  \right)}  = \quad \quad (1)  \cr 
  &  = 40\sum\limits_{r = 1}^{30} {\left( \matrix{
  39 \cr 
  r - 1 \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{
  30 \cr 
  r \cr}  \right)}  = \quad \quad (2)  \cr 
  &  = 40\sum\limits_{r = 0}^{29} {\left( \matrix{
  39 \cr 
  r \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{
  30 \cr 
  r + 1 \cr}  \right)}  = \quad \quad (3)  \cr 
  &  = 40\sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,r\,\left( { \le \,29} \right)} {\left( \matrix{
  39 \cr 
  r \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{
  30 \cr 
  r + 1 \cr}  \right)}  = \quad \quad (4)  \cr 
  &  = 40\sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,r\,\left( { \le \,29} \right)} {\left( \matrix{
  39 \cr 
  r \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{
  30 \cr 
  29 - r \cr}  \right)}  = \quad \quad (5)  \cr 
  &  = 40\left( \matrix{
  69 \cr 
  29 \cr}  \right)\quad \quad (6) \cr} 
$$
where:
 (1) the lower actual index is 1 , since for $r=0$ the product is null,
and the upper is actually $30$ for the second binomial not to be null;
 (2) absorption;
 (3) change index;
 (4) the bounds are implicit in the binomials;
 (5) $0 \le 30$ and we can apply symmetry;
 (6) Vandermonde convolution